# an npm error related to package versions and conflicts

Tags: laravel, npm

I encountered an npm error with the code EOVERRIDE, indicating a conflict between an override for autoprefixer@^10.4.7 and a direct dependency in my project laravel. I attempted to resolve this issue, but now I'm facing another problem: "Unable to locate Mix file: /assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css."
npm ERR! code EOVERRIDE
npm ERR! Override for autoprefixer@^10.4.14 conflicts with direct dependency
Unable to locate Mix file: /assets/vendor/fonts/boxicons.css.